# Reduce number of edge rings

Tags: modeling

I have a tube that has too many edge rings. I would like to reduce them with a 10:1 ratio or something similar. When I try and use a decimate modifier I get bad topology. Is there a non-manual way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Select every other edge loop](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3487/599)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the upcoming 2.71 release there is a better way to achieve this.

- Select edge ring (Ctrl+Alt+RMB)
- Checker De-deselect, *See note below!*
- Select -> Edge Loops
- Mesh -> Delete -> Edge Loops

Note:

*In 2.71 support has been added to deselect alternate edge-ring, See: https://developer.blender.org/T40324
This is detected automatically.*

---

*Previous answer, obsoleted by the method above*

This is possible but a little cumbersome

- In vertex mode select a loop running along the length
- Select -> Checker De-seelct
- Hide
- Set edge mode
- Unhide
- Deselect the vertical loop
- Select -> Edge Loop
- Mesh -> Delete -> Edge Loop

[image]

Footnote, it may be worth adding a **skip** option to edge-ring select, which would make this only 2 steps.

Comment: This is not ideal but it works.

Comment: A tool/option to select every nth edge/face ring would be awesome if it could be done ;)

Comment: @gandalf3, probably we'd just add an option to the existing edge-ring select tool.

Comment: Updated with a less cumbersome method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the dissolve tool... its available in the same menu as the delete options...

1: select edge/vert
2: press <kbd>X</kbd>
3: select your dissolve option

this basically deletes the selected edge/vert without affecting the geometry around it (ie: remove an edge without deleting the connected faces and thereby joining them)

sorry I can't find a single step (automated) way to do this...

related docs:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh