# I can't seem to select faces and edges?

Tags: selection-tools, edges

I'm following this tutorial to get started with blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp1sH6Cm1ww

When I try selecting an edge or a face, the program does not let me. However, I can select vertices, and I can, by result, select edges and face by Ctrl+clicking other vertices, but this is very inefficient and annoying.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In edit mode you can change selection modes by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>. Or just clicking this button in the 3D view header.
[image]
To select edges you want *edge* select mode.

To use more then one selection mode at a time, <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> on ether the buttons in the 3D header or the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> menu.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was... Significantly easier than I thought.

Comment: Out of curiousity in case you look, do you also have any idea how to remove loop subdivisions?

Comment: @user3423509 Feel free to ask a new question, but I think maybe this is what you are looking for: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8157/599

Comment: @user3423509 yes, that is easily done. why dont you ask another question.

Comment: @gandalf3 you even beat me to answer a comment. :)

Comment: Oh okay, I'll do that. I just thought asking many basic questions would "clog" things up. Thats how it is sometimes on these answer sites :) Thanks for the help, I'll make a new question. Also, at the previous user; that is not what I meant. I'll detail my situation a bit more later.

Comment: @David lol :P Btw you might want to add that you can use multiple selection modes at once by shift clicking on the buttons or the options in the `Ctrl Tab` menu.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
Once I selected the *Select Box* it worked fine.

[image: Select Box]