# How to Have Selected Faces Emit Smoke

Tags: edit-mode, smoke-simulation, faces

I'm working on a very large scale project and I want to try to make an object with *Smoke Inflow* but only from certain faces. How would I select or define those certain faces in *Edit Mode*?

Answer (score 1):

Anand mbs is correct about selecting faces, but to use those selected faces in a *Smoke Simulation*, you need to do some more stuff.

### Selecting The Faces

At the bottom of the *3D Viewport* and while in *Edit Mode*, you can click a button that looks the following to switch into *Face Select mode*.

[image]

However, also while in *Edit Mode*, you can key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open a pop-up menu like the following. You can then either click the bottom option (*Face*) or key <kbd>3</kbd> to have Blender automatically select the third option down.

[image]

### Separating Faces

We're not quite done yet. <kbd>RMB</kbd> select the first face and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> select the rest that you want smoke to emit from. Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the faces. Key <kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the *Se<kbd>P</kbd>aration* pop-up menu. It looks like the following. Key <kbd>1</kbd> or click on *Selection* to separate the faces from the original mesh.

[image]

### Smoke Simulation

<kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode*. Select the mesh that is made up of the separated faces. This will be your *Inflow* object. It is also probably wise to *Parent* the faces mesh to the original. Parenting will guarantee that the faces mesh follows the original during transforms. Select the faces mesh, then the original, then key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and either <kbd>2</kbd> or select *Object (Keep Transform)* from the resulting pop-up menu.

Comment: No need to duplicate or separate the faces. Just select the faces, assign them to a vertex group, and use that vertex group on the smoke simulation.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

you can change the selection mode from the above option. 1) vertices, 2) edge, 3) face.

Refer https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/faces.html

also refer [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14307/25176)

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information. If you want to set up those faces so you can select them easier, you can assign them to their own vertex group and then select that to get to them.

Comment: Your answer talks about selecting faces, but not how to incorporate them in a _Smoke Simulation_.

Comment: @ShadyPuck , at first I am sure that the smoke simulation was not mentioned. The question is edited

Comment: @anandmbs You can check the editing history and see that it indeed was.