# What is the difference between an edge loop and an edge ring?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, edges, terminology

I've heard the terms "edge *ring*" and "edge *loop*". What do they mean and how are they different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Edge Loop

An edge loop is a series of directly connected edges:

[image]

You can select an edge loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>.

## Edge Ring

An edge ring is a series of edges which are not directly connected, but share faces:

[image]

You can select an edge ring with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>.

---

As a bonus, you can run the *select edge loop* or the *select edge ring* operator on every selected edge automatically by pressing *Edge loop* or *Edge ring* in *3D view > Header > Select*.