# How to checker deselect edge and vertex rings

Tags: modeling, edges

I know there's a way to checker deselect a ring of edges, but is there a way to do the same on multiple rings of edges or vertices? Every time I've tried it, Blender deselects only the active ring.

I'd like it to look something like this, but doing it manually for larger objects is extremely annoying.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3487/599

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you're wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks, but I was hoping for edge and vertex loops...

Comment: @MasterHolbytla See the second part of my answer

Comment: @gandalf3 I can't get it to work. What exactly do you mean in that answer?

Comment: The workflow for doing this was improved a lot right after I wrote that answer, and it looks like I made things confusing by trying to edit the same instructions to describe both the old and new workflows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since my answer [this similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3487/599) is somewhat outdated, here's a new answer.

## Edge loops

1. Ensure you're in edge select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
2. Select an [edge ring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/11038/599) by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> over an edge
3. Run checker deselect (the <kbd>Space</kbd> search is useful here)
4. Run multi select loops

[image]

Note that this selects edge *loops* as shown in your example. To do the same for [edge rings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/11038/599), do the inverse:

## Edge rings

1. Ensure you're still in edge select mode
2. Select an edge *loop* this time (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>)
3. Run checker deselect
4. Run multi select loops, then enable *rings* in the redo menu (<kbd>F6</kbd> or *3D view > Toolshelf*)

[image]