# UV maping a sphere to have stripes runing between both poles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I tried to map a country flag on a UV sphere, but I could not get it laid out the way how I wanted to see it. I used the Poland flag. 
I wanted to map it exactly as you can see in picture 1.

[image: picture 1]

But what I got was a result as you can see in these pictures.
[image: picture 2a]

[image: picture 2b]

The flag was looped at least 8 times on each half side of the sphere.
I could double that, but I could not go half of that, or less.
I wanted the flag to show up just 1 time at each half side of the sphere.
or maybe twice at each side, but not 8 times. 
as you can see on the third picture, I tried to resize the UV map, but also then it would never go under 8 repeats.
How can I change this?

Here is the [Poland flag texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cNNJ.jpg).

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection

Comment: thanks again for a fast replay 
 but the result is not the solution to the question as you can see in picture 1 that i showed at the beginning.
 i added now a new picture with the result for you to see how is the difference.
 i even tried to rotate this UVmap 90% but that didn't do the job.
i already tried all of the UVwrap possibilities
 but non of them seems to do this very simple basic task.
 there must be another way to get it right. 
also youtube has no tutorials about it, i looked everywhere.. 
 am i missing something ?

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2n1azoj&s=8#.VPPqxNzyBFw

Comment: Your image doesn't fit the UV map in UV editor select all 'A' and scale it down 'S' + mouse movement.

Comment: any image size i try has the same result , no matter the size. 
the result of horizontal flaglines came from 
project from view (bounds).
but to unwrap it in sphere projection make the flag lines go vertical , just as i want them to be, 
but unwrap there has the problem of having scrambled poles as you can see in pict 5 that i added now. 
http://i62.tinypic.com/j9wx9u.jpg
in pict1 that i added earlier , you can see the poles look clean . 
 how do i get the vertical flag texture poles clean without scrambling when using unwrap in sphere projection ?

Comment: are you looking to have just one red and one white stripe on the front of the sphere, without any of the curved distortion?

Comment: hello david , i want the final result exactly as i showed in picture 5 , http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j9wx9u&s=8#.VPSDj9zyBFw, but with clean poles in stead of them having scrambled. i hope you know a way , hope to hear from you soon , thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do it backwards, so instead of unwrapping an icosphere you create a plane and turn it into a sphere, you have a lot more control on the results.
To turn a plane into a sphere see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053/1853)

Unwrapping a plane will give you perfect UVs to do what you want:

[image]

***[.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34774) file***

related:

[What is the best way to unwrap a sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere)
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13927/1853

Comment: Unwrapping Icospheres has always been an issue in all 3D software.

Comment: to be more specific , the beginning and the end of the plane are brought together and where they touch each other ,they create a double line , in stead of just one line .

Answer (score 4):

While you could unwrap the sphere and then texture it, in this case it will be easier to just use a generated texture.

The first method simply differentiates the colors based on the selection. You can easily select the edge loops with the method in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/11035/2217) answer. You will have to manually select the few faces at the poles.
Here I put a white material on the ball, selected the faces that should be red then added [another material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/2217) and hit *Assign*. You could also use vertex colors with this method.
[image: ball with selection]

The second method uses only one material, it creates the stripes with a gradient texture. Here are the nodes used to make the stripes in cycles.
Using object coordinates as the vector, a *Gradient Texture* node set to *Radial* creates the base for the stripes. The *ColorRamp* node set to *Constant* colors the stripes and makes the stripes distinct.
[image: cycles material nodes]

Here is an example ball rendered using the above nodes.
[image: render of a striped red and white ball]

Comment: it is beautiful and perfect for a result how i want it, but in this way i will never be able to quickly change between several textures while searching for a better jpg , or change the amount of the vertical color lines .

Answer (score 1):

To to top view and unwrap using **project from view (bounds)**

[image]

Now what you are looking for is to invert the UV map for one half of the Sphere, so select only one half of the faces

[image]

and in the UV/Image editor window, rotate your UV map 180 degrees (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: the first option is not gonna work for me , because i want to work with jpg textures only.the second option seems to do the job, but i have hundreds of jpg textures, and i want to switch easy from one texture to the next texture . also i like to be able to change the repeat loops with just a click , something similar like click S for resize in the composite window , like in the pict2 that i showed before. this workaround that you show me , seems like i have to mess around with the nodes each time when i want to increase fewer or more loop repeats. is that the only way to do this job  ?

Comment: @elmentor I was using the image you posted. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @elmentor what do you mean by 1st and 2nd option?

Comment: you gave me two options , the 1st option is without ups , and that is not gonna work for me , the second option is with jpg , so that is better for me . because i want to work with custom jpgs

Comment: @elemantor I was describing the process... I guess we're just not understanding what you ask. Please reformulate your question...

Answer (score 0):

i tried to find another way and simply deleted the poles , than made a UV map from this sphere without poles., 
then putting the poles back by E for extrude. en S size to "0" 
in this way you can repeat the texture as you desire,also less then 8 repeated loops , which was not possible before. 
you can even export this as an object and import it in other projects.
 the problem here is that it works for certain simple textures only , but  for complex textures it would still look uncomfortably scrambled at the poles.