# Smart Selection Increase like Modo

Tags: selection-tools

Modo has this nice feature where you can use the up-arrow key to increase the selection in a smart way. Let's say for example I have a face selelection in a line like this: (x is selected, _ is not)

X__X__X____________________

and I hit the up arrow in modo a few times it would recognize the pattern of "select one, skip two and select one face" to give you this.

X__X__X__X__X__X__X__X__X__X

I couldn't find anything in blender that does this. Or is there an addon?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/select-every-other-face-loop/11035#11035

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closet tool I can think of is **Checker Diselect**.
Select all of the faces/edges/verices you want to affect and go to select->Checker Diselect  (or press the space bar and type *checker*)

To further refine your selection activate the tools options by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image]

Comment: @ cegaton how do you make and upload a moving image? :)

Comment: @FacebFaceb use a program that captures GIFs  (like Licecap or GifCam)   read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-can-i-insert-videos-into-my-qa/638#638