# How can I select every Nth edge in only one direction on a plane?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

- Using Nth in shortest path requires selecting every every length of vertices.
- I've tried manipulating checker select.
- Select similar selects all edges in one direction. Adjusting the threshold doesn't help.
- I don't know how to write for select pattern.
- All the other similar questions don't help.

**I'd like this pattern.**

[image]

Comment: Is repeating an action for each row (instead of row * column) an option for you?

Comment: What are you trying to do?... would it be easier to do the shape you are after with an array?

Comment: The mesh is very large, it would take just as long as using the shortest path select mode I mentioned above.

Comment: If there's no way to select the pattern, then the array modifier works great -- just have to reapply a few properties. I'm trying to dissolve all edges on the axis perpendicular to the edges selected above, except only for every other column.

Comment: @360ueck you should consider the new answers and vote on them respectively mark that [other](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50535/2843) pretty simple one from Dan as answered instead of yours as it is way simpler.

Comment: @Samoth I've already marked my answers, but thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do that. Several steps can maybe be improved, but here is my solution:

1. Select an Edge and select similar> direction.

[image]

2. With Border (De)select, deselect all edges at the left and right border.

   - Border select = <kbd>B</kbd> click and release left-mouse-button to select the area
   - Border deselect = <kbd>B</kbd> like select but release mousebutton while pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>

[image]

3. Select all edges at the left side with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>, then choose checker deselect.

[image]

Repeat this for the right side. Make sure the selections at the left and right border are not on the 'same level' (or exactly proportional). You can achieve this by adjusting the offset. Look at the screenshot in step 5 if don't understand what I mean by 'same level' (or proportional).

[image]

4. Select the edges near the left and right border to connect the selections at the border, like it is in the following screenshot. To do this press <kbd>C</kbd> to enable circle-select and follow the 'red lines'.

   - select while in circle select-mode = <kbd>LMB</kbd>
   - deselect while in circle select-mode = [Scroll wheel button]

[image]

5. Then once again, choose checker deselect.
   [image]

Afterwards, it will maybe look like this:
[image]

This can be changed by adjusting the offset.
[image]

6. Deselect all Border edges with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>.

Note: If the whole border becomes selected instead of deselected, repeat it and it will be deselected

Finally it should look like this:
[image]

I hope I could help, and it's clear enough to understand.

Comment: Everything works, except the last step. The entire border became selected and repeating didn't help. The text was a little difficult to understand, but I edited it to hopefully remedy that.

Comment: Make sure you pressed [shift] + [alt] + [RMB] while (de)selecting also move your mousecursor clearly to an edge. Or wasn't it the problem?

Comment: Yes that was it, got it now. Thanks for your good problem solving.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in 3 easy steps:

1. *Edge select* one Edge with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>.
2. Click on *Select* > *Checker Deselect* (<kbd>F6</kbd> for Nth Selection, Skip and Offset)
3. Click on *Select* > *Edge Rings*

   [image]

You just have to deselect the top and the bottom edge.
 In the .gif it is done with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>.

Further Reading on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/11035/19287).

---

Further Information:

After using *Checker Deselect* you can adjust the desired *Nth Selection* at the bottom in the *Toolshelf Panel* or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

> Nth Selection
>         Number of points to select.
>   Skip
>         Number of points to skip.
>   Offset
>         Offests at what point to start at.

quoted from the [Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/selecting.html?highlight=checkers#checker-deselect)

Answer (score 0):

In Face Mode:

1. Select All Faces.
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, and Deselect Every Other Column.
3. Switch to Edge Mode.
4. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, and Deselect Every Column.

Like this:

[image: SelectHorizontalEdgesAtEveryOtherColumn]

Comment: The very first line of my question shows i'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Sorry, that statement sounded to me like you were trying not to select/deselect along its entire length (like a border select or something on every nth column), which is the primary reason I showed how to reduce that down to a single edge on every column.

Answer (score -1):

With much less steps than [DrRiisTab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/23431/drriistab)s [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50392/2843) you can just:

- Alternate loop select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> a vertical edge row:

  [image: Selected vertical Edge loop]
- Add the following vertical loops to your selection via <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>:

  [image: Added loop Selection]
  This is the only part where you have to walk along one side of your whole plane and select every other vertical loop. *Unfortunately, the Repeat Last command doesn't work for Selections.*
- Border (<kbd>B</kbd>)- Deselect (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>-drag) your bottom and top row to get your final result.

  [image: Deselct border row]