# How do I create this crease effect on glass?

Tags: modeling, objects

I am trying to create a vase that looks similar to this:

[image: Vase i'm trying to make]

If there is another post out there I will happily remove this one or redirect it there.

Specifically, I am trying to create the creased effect in the geometry that looks like it is twisting around the vase.

I have tried using Checker Deselect and extrude->scaling the verts but that really screws up my mesh.

Link to my model if it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm sure there are other solutions but i came to an very fast result with the help of the **Screw Modifier**.

[image]
*click for flowerpower (Margarita by [INFAMEDAVID](http://www.blendswap.com/user/InfameDavid))*

The advantage of this modifier is that you can build your mesh with the desired angle of the *Edge Loops* which makes it a lot easier to model the creases.

---

### Model

- add a circle <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- add the **Screw Modifier**

  I used following settings:

  [image]

  *You can use <kbd>Z</kbd> for wireframe to see the result*

---

- apply the Screw Modifier
- add a **Solidify** and a **Subdivision Surface Modifier**
- bring the object into the shape

  [image]

---

Like you mentioned in your Question I also used a combination of *Checker Deselect*, selecting *Edge Rings* and *Edge Loops* to get the desired Selection and scaling it on the X and Y Axis.

<kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

---

### Node-Setup

[image]
I used this Glass Shader Setup from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2565/19287)

---

---

### If you like to edit your existing model:

You can use *Propotional Editing* <kbd>O</kbd>

- to rotate <kbd>R</kbd> your mesh around the Z-Axis
- to scale <kbd>S</kbd> on X and Y axis to create the creases

  [image]
  [image]
  *You control the size of Propotional Editing with the Mousewheel*

For more Information how to get every Nth Selection you can have a look here:

- [How can I select every Nth edge in only one direction on a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50535/19287)
- [Select every other face loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3487/19287)