# How to make spiral vase in blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

I'm looking to build a simple vase for 3d printing and I'm keen to understand how I can do this.

[image]

I've tried the screw modifier, however it appears to be lacking the right level of detail to work properly (I've create a simple shape and then applied several subdivides to it in order to increase the mesh density)

There's bound to be a smart way to achieve this, appreciate any pointers/tips!

Comment: does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68948/19287) help?

Comment: Perfect, will have a look!

Answer (score 5):

### Tissue addon

You can start by using the Screw modifier on a Curve profile in order to build the main shape.

[image]

Then build a "component" for the Tissue add-on made of 3 ridges like the one shown below:

[image]

Run the Tessellate operator chossing the component ad the surface. Activate the merge option.

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for sharing your knowledge :).