# Programmatically selecting every nth edge loop in a mesh?

Tags: python, edges

I need a programatic way to select every nth edge loop in a mesh, in a certain plane. (In the examples below I've shown a mesh with only 12 x/y subdivisions, but in practice my meshes have hundreds of divisions – far too many to select by hand.)

[image]

Is there a common solution for this? Or a script I could look at and learn from? I've tried using python – https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.mesh.html –  for this, but I'm not familiar enough with things to get any practical results. Would love to learn, though.

FWIW I've tried selecting all edge loops in a certain plane, and then using "checker deselect" to achieve the same result, but that doesn't do what I want.[image]

Thanks very much,

Dunstan

Comment: are your meshes always grids like this?

Comment: They are, yes. The only difference between them is the number of subdivisions. (And thanks for helping!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following instructions from the [related answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/select-every-other-face-loop) you can select them with UI as well.

1. Select one edge perpendicular to the resulting edge loops. Run *Edge Ring* from the Edges menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting the edge to select ring of edges based on the first selected edge.

   [image: screenshot-1]
2. Run *Checker Deselect*.

   That's where you will adjust the selection pattern according to which you'd like to select (skip two loops, select the 3-rd, skip one, select the other one etc). The only difference is that you act on only one edge corresponding to each loop.

   [image: screenshot-2]
3. Finally execute *Edge Loops* from the *Select* menu in the 3D Viewport header or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to spread selection on the adjacent edge loops.

   [image: screenshot-3]

Comment: Well damnit, I can't believe that. I initially went through all those steps, but the very last part escaped me and I assumed I couldn't use that tool. Yes, that does seem to be a more practical solution. Thank you, WKG.

Answer (score 5):

By assuming your grid will be parallel to the x-y axis and not rotated, I came up with this idea. It works fine for me and hope this helps.

```
import bpy, bmesh

# These are the parts that you can change, inputs
step_size =            5
first_selected_loop =   0
x_or_y_parallel =      "x"

# Switching to EDIT mode to read mesh data
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Program will get the zeroth index or first index of vertices 
# (that is x or y coordintes) according to your choice
if x_or_y_parallel   == "x":
    x_y_index = 0
elif x_or_y_parallel == "y":
    x_y_index = 1


# Getting the mesh data
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
bm  = bmesh.new()
bm  = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

# Getting all line coordinates that is parallel to selected axis

# I am assuming we don't know how many lines we got in x or y axis
line_x_or_y_cords = []
for vert in bm.verts:
    if vert.co[1-x_y_index] not in line_x_or_y_cords:
        line_x_or_y_cords += [vert.co[1-x_y_index]]

# I am sorting the line coordinates and
# eliminating unwanted coordinates (we need only the lines that are on 
# step size by starting first_selected_loop)
line_x_or_y_cords.sort()
line_x_or_y_cords = line_x_or_y_cords[first_selected_loop::step_size]

# if the edge is not selected yet , if 2 vertex of that edge is 
#parallel to our expected axis and if one of its vertex is in our list 
# (that is arranged above) select that edge and do select loop 
#operation 
for edge in bm.edges:
    if edge.select == False and (edge.verts[0].co[1-x_y_index] - edge.verts[1].co[1-x_y_index] == 0) and  edge.verts[0].co[1-x_y_index] in line_x_or_y_cords:
        edge.select = True
        bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring=False)
bm.free()
```

Comment: Hooray! Thanks so much, Alperen! That script runs perfectly when I put it in a txt file and click "Run Script", but cutting and pasting it into the console gives me a small error:

`File "<blender_console>", line 5
    bm.free()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: That's really going to help my project advance. Thank you again for putting so much effort into helping me :)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help:) I have blender 2.78a and I don't get any errors. You can delete bm = bmesh.new() and bm.free() lines if you wish, it still works:)

Comment: Also, sometimes blender just closes after I run the code and I don't know why:)

Comment: Ah yes, my blender closed a few times too after running it :) Perhaps there's something in there that freaks it out. Well thank you so much for going to the trouble of writing all that code for me. I see that there's another solution posted here that's probably more practical since it uses built in tools, but I really appreciate your answer too!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness too, I upvoted the answer you said since it seems much more simpler:)

Comment: @AlperenÜretmen.

The code you posted works nice though I have 1 request
Can it be modified with z Coord? to only select edges on specific height? 
Please see this post
maybe you have better idea on how to solve my question
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162456/select-edge-loop-of-mesh-using-python