# how to repeat automatic: three selected one skip mesh edge?

Tags: modeling

How to repeat automatic, or full: three selected one skip mesh edge?

[image]

Comment: you could try to select similar by length with Shift+G

Comment: I tried not working :/

Comment: it should work at least kind of. Select one edge in edge select mode and press Shift+G > Length and then if its not working go to your tool shelf (press T if needed) and at the bottom of that change the threshold value.

Comment: If something isn't working as you expected then provide explanation what isn't working and what you expected to happen. "Not working" is not descriptive and vague.

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/select-every-other-face-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [*Checker Deselect*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#checker-deselect) to deselect some edges and leave others selected according to the pattern.

To make it run properly select the full ring of edges where are located those shown on your screenshot. If you want complete ring of edges selected then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and click with <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the edge.

[image: screenshot-of-orange-edges-of-the-mesh]

Make sure to choose active edge as in the screenshot (it is marked with red color, the leftmost one), so it corresponds to those which should be left selected.
Then execute *Checker Deselect*. Set its properties so it deselects every 2nd element and preserves the pattern of 3 edges together. Set the starting point of the selection with *Offset*, in this case it's 2.

[image: screenshot-of-checker-deselect-menu-over-viewport]