# Un-Subdivide Sapling Mesh - Or High Poly to Low Poly

Tags: mesh, loop, sapling-addon

I am ultimately trying to take a sapling tree mesh and create a low poly mesh out of it. So I am manually removing small branches and doing edge loop deletions by hand. Auto un-subdivide modifier does not keep the quad structure.

Is there an efficient way to make these meshes lower poly? I would like a fast way to remove "every other" edge loop if possible.

Here is what I do manually:

[image: removing edge loops]

but there are hundreds of branches to do this on.

Comment: Maybe try a Decimate modifier (must be in Object Mode - Wireframe to see the results), or possibly a Remesh Modifier.

Comment: The decimate modifier does not produce a clean result. Unwrapping then becomes impossible. This is for game usage. I can try a remesh tho!

Comment: Remesh doesn't create a clean mesh whatsoever, unless I am using the wrong settings

Comment: I found this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/select-every-other-face-loop. Helps automate some of the process, but would be cool to streamline this somehow.